# Cannot find symbol "new"

Tags: java

Ok, I looked through a lot of forums in this website and I cannot find my problem.  I keep getting an error stating "cannot find symbol" and points to the "n" in "new" on my EmployeeTest app.  Here is my code:

first file:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Employee

{

    private String fName;
    private String lName;
    private Double mSalary;

    public Employee( String first, String last, Double mth)
    {
        fName = first;
        lName = last;
        if ( mth > 0.00 )
            mSalary = mth;

        if ( mth < 0.00 )
            mSalary = 0.00;
    }

    public void setFName( String first )
    {
        fName = first;
    }

    public void setLName( String last )
    {
        lName = last;
    }

    public void setMSalary( Double mth )
    {
        mSalary = mth;
    }

    public String getFName()
    {
        return fName;
    }

    public String getLName()
    {
        return lName;
    }

    public Double getMSalary()
    {
        return mSalary;
    }

    public void displayMessage()
    {
        System.out.printf( "%s %s has a monthly salary of $%.2f\n",
            getFName(),
            getLName(),
            getMSalary() );
    }
}
```

Second file:

```
public class EmployeeTest

{

    public static void main( String[] args )
        {
            Employee myEmployee = new Employee( 
                "Fred", "Rogers", "10" );

            System.out.printf( "Employee's first name is: %s\n",
                myEmployee.getFName() );
            System.out.printf( "\nEmployee's last name is: %s\n",
                myEmployee.getLName() );
            System.out.printf( "\nEmployee's monthly salary is: %d\n",
                myEmployee.getMSalary() );
        }
}
```

I have a feeling it has to do with my constructor but I cannot find out what the problem is!  I must have looked over my code a ka-jillion times!

Comment: Try changing "10" to 10 or 10.0 You have it as a double in your constructor and you're passing it a string

Comment: @tigrang I think you should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Is not just this one problem here,see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

changing `EmployeeTest`

```
Employee myEmployee = new Employee("Fred", "Rogers", "10" );
```

to:

```
Employee myEmployee = new Employee( "Fred", "Rogers", 10d );
```

and:

```
System.out.printf( "\nEmployee's monthly salary is: %d\n", myEmployee.getMSalary() );
```

to:

```
System.out.printf( "\nEmployee's monthly salary is: %f\n", myEmployee.getMSalary() );
```

Comment: Good catch with the formatting. Wouldnt `%.2f` be better for currency (or however 2 decimal places is, can't remember)?

Comment: Awesome!  It worked!  But I'm now getting this: "Employee's monthly salary is: 10.000000"  How do I limit it to two decimal places?

Comment: `%.2f`, or last line to:`System.out.printf( "\nEmployee's monthly salary is: %s\n",new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(myEmployee.getMSalary()));`

Answer (score 3):

You have `public Employee( String first, String last, Double mth)` as your constructor, but you are instantiating a `Employee` object with `new Employee("Fred", "Rogers", "10");`

The error is most likely saying that it cannot find a constructor which takes `(string, string, string)` arguments.

Change the `"10"` to a `10`: `new Employee("Fred", "Rogers", 10);`

Comment: very good point but it is still doing it.  I changed the "10" to 10 but no change...

Comment: IIRC, passing 10 to a double is fine, but passing 10.0 to an int is not. Just to be sure, pass 10.0 instead. Paste the actual error as well

Answer (score 3):

The constructor in your class is:

```
public Employee( String first, String last, Double mth)
```

but you are calling

```
Employee myEmployee = new Employee( "Fred", "Rogers", "10" );
```

**Either** change the constructor to pass a `String`

```
public Employee( String first, String last, String mth)
```

or pass `10.0` as a double value(which seems to be a better solution).

```
Employee myEmployee = new Employee( "Fred", "Rogers", 10.0d );
```